# Pictures folder disappeared from favorites in file browser

Tags: directory, filemanager, symbolic-link

I recently removed the defautlt Pictures folder and replaced it with a symlink to a different directory.

Now it's no longer in the favorites bar on the left in the file manager. I added it manually to the bottom for now, but I'd still rather have it back where it is by default.
Ubuntu LTS 18.04.

[image]

Comment: The behavior in Ubuntu 19.04 is that if you use the **exact** name (carefully Capitalized) it will appear as you expected. For example, I tested something like: `cd ~ ; rmdir Music ; ln -s ~/Document/my_music Music` and it worked as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this file:

```
$ cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs

# This file is written by xdg-user-dirs-update
# If you want to change or add directories, just edit the line you're
# interested in. All local changes will be retained on the next run
# Format is XDG_xxx_DIR="$HOME/yyy", where yyy is a shell-escaped
# homedir-relative path, or XDG_xxx_DIR="/yyy", where /yyy is an
# absolute path. No other format is supported.
# 
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Set the directory for `XDG_PICTURES_DIR` to reflect your recent changes.